# laravel 5.1 : how can i use my route in blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to link to my route in blade. How can i do this?

```
<a href="roue" > go first</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you define Route name you can use that in your blade :

define Route Name :

```
Route::get('/admin/transfer/forms-list', [
    'as'   => 'transfer.formsList',
    'uses' => 'Website\TransferController@IndexTransferForms'
]);
```

now you can use that in your blade like this :

```
<a href="{{URL::route('transfer.formsList')}}"  type="submit">
                        go first</a>
```

Of course if you use form collective you can use this :

```
{!! link_to_route('route.name', 'go first') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to use routes in a view.

1. The simplest one is using [route()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route) helper:

   `<a href="{{ route('route.name') }}">go first</a>`
2. If you're using [Laravel Collective HTML & Forms](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html), it will create full link, not only path to the route:

   `{!! link_to_route('route.name', 'go first') !!}`

   Or:

   `{!! HTML::linkRoute('mainpage', 'hey') !!}`
3. Using URL facade. Wouldn't recommend, because you're getting redundant code:

   `<a href="{{ URL::route('route.name') }}">go first</a>`